# Nodejs request module return incorrect statusCode

Tags: node.js, request, http-status-codes

I'm trying to use request module to get HTTP status code. But sometimes it works wrong. For example:

```
var request = require('request');
var requestSettings = {
    method: 'HEAD',
    url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/help'
};
request(requestSettings, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
});
```

This code returns 404 (not 200 as expected).
Why might this happen?
Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be specific to node. When `curl http://stackoverflow.com/help -I` also returns 404 while `curl http://stackoverflow.com/help -i` shows 200. Guess SO dosen't like HEAD requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing everything fine. stackoverflow didn't implement HEAD

[image: telnet HEAD request]